# How do you match a string with single quote in mysql from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that has a column called title which is a string.

When the string has a single quote however (e.g. "John's group"), the sql fails.

I'm using the following php code to lookup the table:

```
$pageID = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT pageID FROM `mytable` WHERE title='" . $title . "'"));
```

where $title contains my lookup string.

Can anybody give me advise on what to do here?

EDIT: I've discovered that two single quotes will work in the SQL - however - is there a way to do this in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape your `title` before using in the query.

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try string replacing ' characters with '' to escape it in your overall query:

```
$pageID = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT pageID FROM `mytable` WHERE title='" . str_replace($title, "'", "''") . "'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$pageID = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT pageID FROM `mytable` WHERE title="' . $title . '"'));
```